# Is it possible for Clarion to load a web page within a Clarion window?

Tags: development-environment, clarion

I've been asked to investigate if it is possible for Clarion 5 to load a web page within a Clarion window, not in a separate web browser.

I've already tried using an OLE control and hyperlink from CapeSoft, and these work opening in a new web browser window.

I've read that I can use an OCX control and change the property to load a website but I tried to load Google as a sample and it wasn't loaded inside my Clarion window but in a separate web browser.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

That is my code:

```
OF EVENT:OpenBrowser
    WebBrowser  = CREATE(0,CREATE:OLE)
    WebBrowser{PROP:Create} = 'InternetExplorer.Application'
    WebBrowser{'Visible'}   = True
    UrlString = 'http://google.com.au'
    WebBrowser{'Navigate(' & UrlString & ')'}**
```

Comment: Refer http://www.attryde.com/clarion/cw_ieocx.htm for using OLE control to open a webpage inside clarion window. I hope this might help you

Answer (score 1):

[Capesoft File Explorer](http://capesoft.com/accessories/FileExplorer.htm) can embed a web browser in a Clarion window.